# HTML Formatting Form Response as %

Tags: html, format

I've got a Google Form set up and for one of the questions a percentage value is entered for the answer.

I then generate an email with some of the answers included, however the percentage value shows as, for example, "0.25" instead of "25%".

I've tried a few different bits of code such as .getDataValues, .formatString, .setNumberFormat etc but none of them work.

My code is:

```
    var lastrow =    formResponses.getLastRow() 
    var lastColumn =    formResponses.getLastColumn()
    var Setup_Array = formResponses.getRange(2,1,lastrow,lastColumn).getValues()

                   for (i in Setup_Array) {
                   var row = Setup_Array[i];   
                   row.rowNumber = parseInt(i)

    var percent = row[17];
```

I'm also having the same issue with a date response, where it's including time and timezone, whereas I just want it to show the date.

Any help would be appreciated!